# How to best light up small walk-in closet?

Tags: lighting, closet

### Context

I have a couple small walk-in closets in my apartment: they are 1-door-plus-few-centimetres wide (60–75cm) and fairly deep (95cm). The doors open from a hallway without direct natural light.

This, plus one's own shadow when standing in the doorway makes that the inside is fairly dark.

I intend to use the cabinets for: laundry (stacked washer + dryer), shelved cupboard, coats + broom.

### Question

**How to best light up such small walk-in closets?**

---

My own  research so far is:

- I want the closets to **automatically light up when the door is open** (lighting would be beneficial at any time of the day and I am way to lazy to open a door *and* turn the light on — plus I'm sure I would forget to turn it off).
- I plan to bring electricity through the closets anyway, so **power supplied appliances is an option**.

What I have found is:

- [Motion sensor LED stick](https://web.archive.org/web/20200425111856/https://www.amazon.co.uk/LOFTer-Rechargeable-Wardrobe-Anywhere-Cupboard/dp/B07RDK7Z3C): I have one like this in my garage and it woks quite well but:

  - it is battery powered,
  - installed over the door: it wouldn't light up bottom shelves (plus there is still my own shadow)
  - installed on both side, at torso height: I fear they might fall or get knocked over as it's only hold magnetically.
- [LED strips](https://web.archive.org/web/20200425111941/https://www.amazon.co.uk/Low-Voltage-Striplight-Non-Waterproof-Lighting-Backlight/dp/B00HSF65MC) along the door frame: this would solve the shadow issue, but:

  - I'm still concerned about the fixing via 3M tape
  - I'm not sure how to best switch the light on when door is open (motion sensor, physical switch when door is closed, IR switch?).
- Regular light bulbs (as suggested [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/15776/90042)) don't seem like a real option (too bulky).

Comment: I'd firmly suggest the physical switch, like on a refrigerator door. I'd also suggest thinking beyond the doorframe for light strip placement (*i.e.* no reason you can't have some midway or even all the way at the back, under each shelf, etc.)

Comment: A reed switch operated by a magnet on the door - magnet opens the contacts when closed...

Comment: Shopping advice isn't encouraged here, but I can say that Ikea has, in the past and probably future, sold battery operated motion sensor lights that are completely decent. Trades occasional battery changes for the bother of running wire in the first place.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Thanks for the advice! A bi-yearly battery charge is indeed an acceptable trade-off. (I'd also like to clarify that *I am indeed* not *looking for shopping recommendation, but rather generic* types of solution *and best practices* — Ecnerwal and Solar_Mike's comments are, in this regard, exactly what I'm looking for. The products I'm linking to are for illustrative purpose only.)